# When exactly catastrophic backtracking error happens?

Tags: php, regex

Sometimes I will be faced with **catastrophic backtracking** when I'm writing regex pattern. For example, in [this content](https://regex101.com/r/N1j4De/2), as you see pattern below matches one thing as well:

```
/Jakob Finch/
```

But pattern below throws [*catastrophic backtracking*](https://regex101.com/r/N1j4De/3) error:

```
/style.*?Jakob Finch/
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Use proper tools to parse HTML/XML. Even the best unrolled regex (like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/HVnqSH/1)) can cause slowdown/catastrophical backtracking depending on the input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to use regex to parse XML. I'm just trying to understand when exactly **catastrophic backtracking** error occurs? And why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: There is an SO question that deals with catastrophic backtracking in general. Let me find it...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you .. if you find it let me know .. however I hope it wasn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751230/regex-pattern-catastrophic-backtracking)

Comment: Well, please check [Catastrophic backtracking shouldn't be happening on this regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378625/catastrophic-backtracking-shouldnt-be-happening-on-this-regex). I think [Alan Moore's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7379269/3832970) can be applied here.